# How do I display missing unique numbers in cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a 5 digit number, e.g., `23450` in one cell. I want to display the digits 0 to 9 that are missing from this number.  In this example, my other cell should display `16789` which are the missing digits. Below is an example:

```
Column A        Column B (should display missing number)
23456          17890
34877          125690
22344          1567890
27788          1345690
```

Note that the number in column A can contain multiples of the same digit, in which case column B would contain more than five missing digits.

I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

My non-VBA solution is similar to Máté Juhász's but without substitution; it simply builds the string:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("0",A1)),"0","")&IF(ISERROR(FIND("1",A1)),"1","")
 &IF(ISERROR(FIND("2",A1)),"2","")&IF(ISERROR(FIND("3",A1)),"3","")
 &IF(ISERROR(FIND("4",A1)),"4","")&IF(ISERROR(FIND("5",A1)),"5","")
 &IF(ISERROR(FIND("6",A1)),"6","")&IF(ISERROR(FIND("7",A1)),"7","")
 &IF(ISERROR(FIND("8",A1)),"8","")&IF(ISERROR(FIND("9",A1)),"9","")
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily achieved with VBA:

```
Public Function uniquenumbers(cellvalue As String)
    originalseries = "1234567890"
    totallength = Len(cellvalue)
    For i = 1 To totallength
        thevalue = Mid(cellvalue, i, 1)
        theposition = InStr(1, originalseries, thevalue)
        If theposition > 0 Then
            originalseries = Mid(originalseries, 1, theposition - 1) & Mid(originalseries, theposition + 1)
        End If
    Next i
    uniquenumbers = originalseries
End Function
```

Open Macros /VBA with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>. Right-click *ThisWorkbook* and insert a *Module*. Paste the code on the right side.

On cell `B2` put `=uniquenumbers(A2)`.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to start with a string of all digits (`0123456789`) then remove each digit which present in the source string, e.g. for `0`:

`=SUBSTITUTE("0123456789",IF(ISERROR(FIND("0",A1)),"","0"),"")`

Then you need to nest it for the next level to work with it's result:

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("0123456789",IF(ISERROR(FIND("0",A1)),"","0"),""),IF(ISERROR(FIND("1",A1)),"","1"),"")`

And for all the digits:

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("0123456789",IF(ISERROR(FIND("0",A1)),"","0"),""),IF(ISERROR(FIND("1",A1)),"","1"),""),IF(ISERROR(FIND("2",A1)),"","2"),""),IF(ISERROR(FIND("3",A1)),"","3"),""),IF(ISERROR(FIND("4",A1)),"","4"),""),IF(ISERROR(FIND("5",A1)),"","5"),""),IF(ISERROR(FIND("6",A1)),"","6"),""),IF(ISERROR(FIND("7",A1)),"","7"),""),IF(ISERROR(FIND("8",A1)),"","8"),""),IF(ISERROR(FIND("9",A1)),"","9"),"")`